# component alignment in HTML does not follow the order I aligned

Tags: css, angular

The purpose of the project files was to practice CSS animation using `@keyframe` along with displaying some different components in Angular2; I've started studying CSS and Angular2 at the same time.

The problem is that the order of tags I set in `<app-root>` template is not applied when loaded on web browser. `<contents>` template must be in the middle but it appears below the `<bottomline>`.

`<body>` tag of `index.html` has `<app-root>` only and the waterfall background image is handled in this file too.

And this is the temple of `<app-root>`.

```
<titlebar></titlebar>
<contents></contents>
<bottomline></bottomline>
```

So the `<contents>` should be in the middle but the result is as below:

[image]

`<titlebar>` and `<bottomline>` has the same structure; the only two  difference are the text within the `<div>` tag and the name of class selectors.

```
<div class="titlebar">
    titlebar!
</div>
```

This is `titlebar.component.css`.

```
div.titlebar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    color: #fff;
}
```

`body.component.html`, which selector name in `.ts` is set to `<contents>`:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one is `body.component.css`. I copied `.outer`, `.middle`, and `.inner` selector from a question in this website to center the `<div>` tag. I don't think the animation makes the problem; The thinks didn't get better when I set the animation codes to comments.

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;}

.inner {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: mainbox;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

@keyframes mainbox{
    from{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 0%;
    }

    to{
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
        height: 80%;
    }
}
```

In my common sense there's no reason for the `<contents>` and `<bottomline>` tags to switch their position.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably because of the `position: absolute` - to test that, change the position to `relative` or `inherent` or something - the reason this would be happening is because when you make something absolute - you are basically taking it OUT of it's natural flow. Think of it as taking it not only out, but floating it on top - allowing other things to fill the space behind it, which is why an element you expect to be below it - has moved up.

Comment: hmm just by deleting what you mentioned the order got back right; now i have to deal with some margin and height problem.. thank you!